# getting error 404 not found while making ajax call on button click

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have written following function to perform an ajax call on button click :

```
function callPrint() {
        var PrintCssContent = "";
        //$.get("/App_Themes/@siteContext.UI.Theme/Print.css", function(cssContent){
        //    PrintCssContent = cssContent;
        //});

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Areas/Travel/Controllers/Itinerary/GetHtmlString",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (cssText) {
                PrintCssContent = cssText;

                var DivMainContent = document.getElementById('mytrip');
                var DivEdit = document.getElementById('divEdit');
                var divlink = document.getElementById('divlink');

                var WinPrint =
                window.open('', '', 'width=auto,height=auto,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes');
                WinPrint.document.write("<html><head><style>" + PrintCssContent + "</style> </head><body>");
                //WinPrint.document.write("<html><head><style> table.faressvcsShorter {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;border-collapse: collapse;margin: 5px;width: 95%;}</style> </head>");

                //divlink.style.display = 'none';
                //WinPrint.document.write(DivEdit.innerHTML.toString());
                //divlink.style.display = 'block';
                WinPrint.document.write("<div class='clear10px'></div><div class='split'></div>");
                WinPrint.document.write(DivMainContent.innerHTML.toString());
                WinPrint.document.write("</body></html>");
                WinPrint.document.close();
                WinPrint.focus();
                WinPrint.print();
                WinPrint.close();
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

And my action method is at following path ;
\Areas\Travel\Views\Itinerary\GetHtmlString

i have 1 button in my page on which i am performing onclick method to make an ajax call
but it's throwing "404 not found" error in console.
is there any solution?

Comment: `/Areas/Travel/Controllers/Itinerary/GetHtmlString` looks like you trying to access a `.cshtml` file,  not an action method. What is the name of the Controller and the ActionResult method, and what Area is it in

Comment: what is your controller name and action method name ?

Comment: controller : Itinerary and action method : GetHtmlString

Comment: public ActionResult GetHtmlString(List<TravelOption> travelOptions, UserRequestContext requestContext, User user, long tripKey, string value = "", string Id = "", string travelReqId = "")

this is my action method

Comment: Then your url should be `/Itinerary/GetHtmlString` (or better `url: '@Url.Action("GetHtmlString", "Itinerary")',`) But if you have Areas, you may also need `new { area = "..." }`

Comment: yes i have areas. then what will be the final path?

Comment: `url: '@Url.Action("GetHtmlString", "Itinerary", new { area = "yourAreaName" })'`

Comment: You should not hard code the URL in the JavaScript function, use the `@Url.Action` to get the correct URL as Stephen suggested, also open the developer toolbar and go to the network tab and click the button and check absolute what URL is being called